# SELECT rows between two dates in azure cosmos db

Tags: datetime, select, azure-cosmosdb

`Date` is stored in the Azure Cosmos DB like that : `"date": "2020-11-18"`

How can a make a query to SELECT the number of rows between two dates (they can be in any format, they come from a datepicker) ?

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE table.date //between date1 and date2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE NOT (From_date > @RangeTill OR To_date < @RangeFrom)
```

You exclude all wrong option, so you find the date between 2 other date